# Celery + SQS - pycurl error

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery, amazon-sqs

Today I have been trying to setup Celery using AWS SQS as the broker, however upon excututing the following:

test.py

```
from celery import Celery

access_key_id = '********************'
secret_access_key = '****************************************'

broker_url = 'sqs://%s:%s@' %(access_key_id, secret_access_key)

app = Celery('test', backend=None, broker=broker_url)

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Attempting to run the Celery worker using the command

```
celery -A test worker --loglevel=info
```

With this I get the following error:

```
Unrecoverable error: ImportError('The curl client requires the pycurl library.',)
```

I have the following packages installed:

```
amqp (2.2.2)
billiard (3.5.0.3)
boto (2.48.0)
boto3 (1.4.7)
botocore (1.7.48)
celery (4.1.0)
docutils (0.14)
jmespath (0.9.3)
kombu (4.1.0)
pip (9.0.1)
pycurl (7.43.0)
python-dateutil (2.6.1)
pytz (2017.3)
s3transfer (0.1.11)
schedule (0.5.0)
setuptools (37.0.0)
six (1.11.0)
vine (1.1.4)
wheel (0.30.0)
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it could be an issue with the version of Celery (4.1.0) that you have. If I execute the same code after downgrading to version 3.1.25 it works fine.

Comment: I tried this and it does fix this particular issue, but it leads to other compatibility issues (in my case with the version of Django), so not sure if this is the ideal solution.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error and these steps worked for me:

mac:

```sh
brew upgrade openssl

export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"   

export PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl

python -m pip install celery[sqs]
```

centos:

```sh
pip uninstall pycurl
export PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=nss
pip install --compile pycurl
```

Comment: Worked for me on Mac!

Comment: This almost worked, but I would (explicitly) say that you need to uninstall pycurl and then reinstall after following those steps. Thank you!

Comment: Note that the LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS paths depend on where your openssl is installed. Run `brew info openssl` to find the paths.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Mac, you need to compile and install PycURL. You may also need to install `openssl` if not already installed.

```sh
brew install openssl
    
export PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl 
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include" 
pip install --no-cache-dir pycurl
```

Similarly for linux to install `openssl`:

```sh
apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev gcc
```

Check the [PycURL SSL Docs](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/install.html#ssl) for further installation info.

Answer (score 0):

This works on Debian

```
sudo apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev
pip uninstall pycurl
pip install pycurl --compile --global-option="--with-openssl" --no-cache-dir
```

Answer (score 0):

If you **don't use *pip install celery[sqs]*** it will work.
Use **pip install celery** and than install the other libraries one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on to BlaShadow's answer (don't have the rep to comment), if PyCurl is already installed you'll need to uninstall it and remove it from the cache:

```
pip uninstall pycurl
pip cache remove pycurl
```

Also if you don't have root access your openssl install will probably be elsewhere. I have mine in my home directory so it looked like this

```
export LDFLAGS=-L/Users/$YOUR_NAME/brew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.2.1/lib;export CPPFLAGS=-I/Users/$YOUR_NAME/brew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.2.1/include
```